# Define class where variadic template size is 1

Tags: c++

I have the following superclass in `typedarray.h`

```
template<typename... Args>
class TypedArray {};
```

`PrimitiveArray`, a subclass of `TypedArray`, will always be constructed with a variadic template of size 1. I'm looking for a way to define `PrimitiveArray` such that this first and only template argument has a class-scope typename. Something like the following:

```
#include typedarray.h

template<typename... Args>
class PrimitiveArray<T> : public TypedArray<Args...> {};
```

This obviously fails because `T` is undefined, and adding `T` to the typedef results in a partial specialization error.

I have defined the class as `PrimitiveArray<Args...>`, unpacking the first template parameter in each method. I feel like there must be a better way to do this. Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is not a specialization.

If you know that `PrimitiveArray` will always have only one type template arguments I think you should write the code to reflect this.

Something like this should work:

```
template<typename... Args>
class TypedArray {};
 
template<typename T>
class PrimitiveArray : public TypedArray<T>
{
    using PrimitiveType = T;
};
 
int main()
{
    PrimitiveArray<int> test;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Haha, I posted answer on incorrect tab of stackoverflow....<.<